# error on a char string with more than 15 characters

Tags: c, char, printf, undefined-behavior, c-strings

why gcc doesn't allow me to work with char dimension >15?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char alphabet[]={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    int dim_alph;
    dim_alph=strlen(alphabet);
    printf("%s has %d characters\n", alphabet, dim_alph);
    return 0;
}`
```

it gives me invalid output on both string and dimension (also if I stopped to the 'P' character but not to 'O' one)

Comment: Your char array isn't an c-string, the nul terminator is missing.

Comment: you need to add '\0' as a character. its the null terminator

Comment: You should do it as `char alphabet[] = "ABC...Z";`.

Comment: In addition to everything else, “dimension” is the wrong word here. The *dimension* of the array, regardless of its length, is 1.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Right, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

As per the current initialization, the array `alphabet` is not null-terminated, so it cant be used as a *string*. Attempt to use it as one (ex: passing it to a function which expects a string), will cause out of bound access (in search of the null terminator) past the allocated memory, an accessing invalid memory invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you have to use if as a string, you need to either

- add a null-terminator in the brace-enclosed initializer list, like `.....'X','Y','Z', '\0'};`
- use a string literal to initialize the array, like `char alphabet[]="ABCD....XYZ";`

Answer (score 0):

The declared array

```
char alphabet[]={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
```

does not contain a string because there is no terminating zero among the initializers.

So the call of `strlen`

```
dim_alph=strlen(alphabet);
```

and using the conversion specifier `%s` in the call of `printf`

```
printf("%s has %d characters\n", alphabet, dim_alph);
```

invoke undefined behavior.

Instead you could write

```
int dim_alph = ( int )sizeof( alphabet );
printf("%.*s has %d characters\n", dim_alph, alphabet, dim_alph);
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char alphabet[] = 
    {
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
        'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
    };

    int dim_alph = ( int )sizeof( alphabet );

    printf("%.*s has %d characters\n", dim_alph, alphabet, dim_alph);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ has 26 characters
```

An alternative approach is to initialize the array with a string literal. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char alphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    int dim_alph = ( int )( sizeof( alphabet ) - 1 );

    printf("%s has %d characters\n", alphabet, dim_alph);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Again the program output is

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ has 26 characters
```